# Adding INNER JOIN to Query With Subquery With Inline Select Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

I have the following SQL which works:

```
Select TRADING_DWKEY,
       M_SM_USER_CODE,
       FIRST_TRADE,
       'New Footprint' Status,
       Null Q4Vol,
       CQVol 
  From (Select A.TRADING_DWKEY||A.RM_SM_USER_CODE,
               A.TRADING_DWKEY,
               A.RM_SM_USER_CODE,
               B.FIRST_TRADE, SUM(A.RISK_AMOUNT_ADJ)/1000000 CQVol
          from FACT_TRADE_ROLLUP A,
               (SELECT TRADING_DWKEY,
                       MIN(FIRST_TRADE_DATE) FIRST_TRADE 
                  FROM ACCOUNT_FIRST_LAST_TRADE_DATES
                  Having MIN(FIRST_TRADE_DATE) >= to_char(trunc((sysdate-1),'Y'),'dd-Mon-yy')
                  GROUP BY TRADING_DWKEY) B
          WHERE A.DATE_KEY>='01-Jan-16' AND
                ((A.PRODUCT_DWKEY IN ('RT') AND  A.Account_Type='Customer') OR
                  A.PRODUCT_DWKEY IN('OB','BS','MM')) AND
                A.Role = 'SM' AND
                A.TRADING_DWKEY = B.TRADING_DWKEY
          GROUP BY A.TRADING_DWKEY||A.RM_SM_USER_CODE,
                   A.TRADING_DWKEY,
                   A.RM_SM_USER_CODE,
                   B.FIRST_TRADE
          HAVING SUM(A.RISK_AMOUNT_ADJ)>=20000000) NewFP;
```

When I attempt to add a INNER JOIN to the subquery (to pull a name instead of a code), I get an error that A.RM_SM_USER_CODE is not a valid identifier on the line where I write the INNER JOIN. However, I am **positive** this field exists in the FACT_TRADE_ROLLUP table. I suspect the error has something to do with where I place the INNER JOIN, but cannot figure it.

Here is the fully modified SQL (but I get the error even if I just place the INNER JOIN statement in without actually modifying the columns.

```
Select TRADING_DWKEY,
       RM_SM_NAME,
       FIRST_TRADE,
       'New Footprint' Status,
       Null Q4Vol,
       CQVol 
  From (Select A.TRADING_DWKEY||A.RM_SM_USER_CODE,
               A.TRADING_DWKEY,
               q.RM_SM_NAME,
               B.FIRST_TRADE,
               SUM(A.RISK_AMOUNT_ADJ)/1000000 CQVol 
          from FACT_TRADE_ROLLUP A,
               (SELECT TRADING_DWKEY, MIN(FIRST_TRADE_DATE) FIRST_TRADE  
                  FROM ACCOUNT_FIRST_LAST_TRADE_DATES
                  Having MIN(FIRST_TRADE_DATE)>=to_char(trunc((sysdate-1),'Y'),'dd-Mon-yy')
                  GROUP BY TRADING_DWKEY) B
  --- error thrown on this line, specifying it at the end
          INNER JOIN REF_RM_SM_REGION q
            on q.RM_SM_USER_CODE = A.RM_SM_USER_CODE
          WHERE A.DATE_KEY>='01-Jan-16' AND
                ((A.PRODUCT_DWKEY IN('RT') AND A.Account_Type='Customer') OR 
                  A.PRODUCT_DWKEY IN('OB','BS','MM')) AND
                A.Role = 'SM' AND
                A.TRADING_DWKEY = B.TRADING_DWKEY
          GROUP BY A.TRADING_DWKEY||A.RM_SM_USER_CODE,
                   A.TRADING_DWKEY,
                   q.RM_SM_NAME,
                   B.FIRST_TRADE
          HAVING SUM(A.RISK_AMOUNT_ADJ)>=20000000) NewFP;
```

Comment: Why are you comparing dates as strings?

Comment: @MT0 - The truth is I am not sure why the dates | string comparison is written that way. I inherited this code and I've been taught it's the way it has to be done with the dataset we have (am learning Oracle and SQL at the moment). Anyway, that's not really a concern here (at least, I don't think), as that part is not causing any issue.

Comment: I think it may be because you've mixed the cartesian product syntax (commas) with the ANSI join syntax (`INNER JOIN`). Change the comma to `CROSS JOIN` or actually do the join on `TRADING_DWKEY`.

Comment: @shawnt00 - can you explain what you mean by *change the comma*? Are you suggesting I change `INNER JOIN` to `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: @Scott Well my suggestion with the minimal change is as I said: `,` -> `CROSS JOIN`. But really you're doing an inner join from A to B so it's probably better to write it that way (and you won't get yelled at.) So then `,` -> `INNER JOIN` and then right after `) B` you write `) B ON B.TRADING_DWKEY = A.TRADING_DWKEY`.

Comment: @Scott Actually why do you have `HAVING` before the `GROUP BY` in that inner query?

Comment: @shawnt00 - frankly I'm surprised it executed with the HAVING before the GROUP BY. Oracle never ceases to amaze me...

Comment: @shawnt00 - to be honest I inherited all this SQL code. Am just learning deeper SQL knowledge myself, but now I am scared of all the code I inherited. I'd rather learn *best* practices ... Thank God for SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any DDL statements defining the tables it is difficult to test but:

1. You are comparing dates using strings - Oracle is probably doing an implicit conversion back to a date using the value of the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter (which is hopefully `DD-MON-YY`) but if this ever changes then it will break the query (and the query won't have changed so it will be a pain to debug). Stop using strings as dates and use date literals - i.e. `DATE '2016-01-01'`.
2. You have the first `HAVING` clause before the `GROUP BY` clause - swap them around.
3. You also are mixing a legacy comma join and ANSI join - replace the comma join with an `INNER JOIN` and move the join condition out of the `WHERE` clause.
4. Grouping by `A.TRADING_DWKEY||A.RM_SM_USER_CODE` is inefficient. You already have `A.TRADING_DWKEY` as one of the `GROUP BY` terms so don't concatenate the strings just include the other column in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Something like:

```
Select TRADING_DWKEY,
       RM_SM_NAME,
       FIRST_TRADE,
       'New Footprint' Status,
       Null Q4Vol,
       CQVol 
From (
  Select A.TRADING_DWKEY,
         q.RM_SM_NAME,
         B.FIRST_TRADE,
         SUM(A.RISK_AMOUNT_ADJ)/1000000 CQVol 
  from   FACT_TRADE_ROLLUP A
         INNER JOIN
         ( SELECT   TRADING_DWKEY,
                    MIN(FIRST_TRADE_DATE) FIRST_TRADE  
           FROM     ACCOUNT_FIRST_LAST_TRADE_DATES
           GROUP BY TRADING_DWKEY
           HAVING   MIN(FIRST_TRADE_DATE)>= trunc(sysdate-1,'Y')
         ) B
         ON ( A.TRADING_DWKEY=B.TRADING_DWKEY )
         INNER JOIN REF_RM_SM_REGION q
         ON ( q.RM_SM_USER_CODE = A.RM_SM_USER_CODE )
  WHERE A.DATE_KEY >= DATE '2016-01-01'
  AND   ( (    A.PRODUCT_DWKEY IN('RT')
           AND A.Account_Type='Customer'
          )
        OR A.PRODUCT_DWKEY IN('OB','BS','MM')
        )
  AND   A.Role = 'SM' 
  GROUP BY A.RM_SM_USER_CODE,
           A.TRADING_DWKEY,
           q.RM_SM_NAME,
           B.FIRST_TRADE
  HAVING SUM(A.RISK_AMOUNT_ADJ)>=20000000
);
```

Comment: thanks for *all* the pointers. data ran as expected now. voting as answer for laying everything nicely for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select TRADING_DWKEY, RM_SM_NAME, FIRST_TRADE, 'New Footprint' Status, Null Q4Vol, CQVol 
From (
    Select
        A.TRADING_DWKEY || A.RM_SM_USER_CODE, /* No name. So is this even used? */
        A.TRADING_DWKEY,
        q.RM_SM_NAME, B.FIRST_TRADE, SUM(A.RISK_AMOUNT_ADJ) / 1000000 CQVol 
    from FACT_TRADE_ROLLUP A INNER JOIN /* <--- Changed here... */
        (
        SELECT TRADING_DWKEY, MIN(FIRST_TRADE_DATE) FIRST_TRADE  
        FROM ACCOUNT_FIRST_LAST_TRADE_DATES
        Having MIN(FIRST_TRADE_DATE)>=to_char(trunc((sysdate-1),'Y'),'dd-Mon-yy')
        GROUP BY TRADING_DWKEY /* Very odd it ran with this after HAVING */
        ) B
            ON B.TRADING_DWKEY = A.TRADING_DWKEY /* <--- ...and here */
        INNER JOIN REF_RM_SM_REGION q on q.RM_SM_USER_CODE = A.RM_SM_USER_CODE
    WHERE
        A.DATE_KEY>='01-Jan-16'
            AND (A.PRODUCT_DWKEY IN('RT') AND A.Account_Type='Customer')
                OR A.PRODUCT_DWKEY IN('OB','BS','MM'))
            AND A.Role = 'SM'
  /* removed line that was here */ 
  GROUP BY
      A.TRADING_DWKEY||A.RM_SM_USER_CODE, A.TRADING_DWKEY,
      q.RM_SM_NAME, B.FIRST_TRADE
  HAVING SUM(A.RISK_AMOUNT_ADJ) > =20000000
) NewFP;
```

I made a minimal effort to clean it up. Hopefully I didn't break it in the process. As noted it was probably the mixing of two types of join syntax that caused the error.

Comment: It ran well, so thank you very much for that! I am also grateful for all the pointers and explanation in the comments. It took a moment, but I got the join type syntax information that you were talking about. I wish I could mark them both as answers, because I really do appreciate the thoroughness with which you helped.I feel like I just learned more with this question than the past two days digging on my own!

Comment: @Scott That's fine. I really only added the answer since it is better for annotating the code than comments are.