# SQL Left Outer Join on Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, outer-join

I am attempting to build a query that contains a left join subquery - based on the principles I learned in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602127/adding-inner-join-to-query-with-subquery-with-inline-select-statement) - that should pull similar data sets from two different tables. The goal is to compare volume data by `account || platform` to ensure that the stored procedure that creates one table from another is doing so correctly.

The idea is this:

```
Account || Product || T1Vol || T2Vol
abc        AT         10        10
def        RT         20        25
ghi        OB         30
```

So with this example, the idea is to pull all accounts and products from T1 (the table the procedure acts on) and any accounts and products from T2 (the newly created table) where there is a match (so, Left Join on T1 = T2). (Ideally, everything will match perfectly, with no variance in T1 vs T2 vol and no nulls in T2 volume).

I wrote the following the query  to accomplish this but its not quite working. The current error I get is `not a GROUP BY expression` - which I don't think is the *real issue*. I have been searching and with iterations to no avail.

The query is below. (To keep with the example, `T1 = OpStats` and `T2 = RegSplits`. Any help is much appreciated.

```
  SELECT DTA.trading_code Account, OpStats.product_dwkey Platform, SUM(OpStats.risk_amount_adj)/1000000 OpStatsVol, RegSplits.Volume RegSplitsVol
  FROM fact_trade_presplit_rollup OpStats
  INNER JOIN dim_trading_accounts DTA ON OpStats.trading_dwkey=DTA.trading_dwkey
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                  ( SELECT b.trading_Code Account, a.product_dwkey Platform, SUM(a.risk_amount_adj)/1000000 Volume
                    FROM fact_trade_rollup a 
                    INNER JOIN dim_trading_accounts b on a.trading_dwkey=b.trading_dwkey
                    WHERE a.account_type IN('Customer','Taker') 
                      AND a.date_key>='01-JAN-16' 
                      AND a.date_key<='31-MAR-16'
                      AND a.daily_db_metric NOT IN ('Manual Treasury Volume ($B)', 'Manual Volume ($B)', 'HSBC-WL POMS (Internal) Volume ($B)','JPMC-WL Order Book (Internal) Volume ($B)')
                      AND (a.product_dwkey IN('RT','HWL') AND a.source_name<>'STP')
                    GROUP BY b.trading_code, a.product_dwkey ) RegSplits
                ON (DTA.trading_code = RegSplits.Account) /* is it because I am trying to join DTA to the subquery */
  WHERE OpStats.account_type IN('Customer','Taker') 
    AND OpStats.date_key>='01-JAN-16' 
    AND OpStats.date_key<='31-MAR-16'
    AND OpStats.daily_db_metric NOT IN ('Manual Treasury Volume ($B)', 'Manual Volume ($B)', 'HSBC-WL POMS (Internal) Volume ($B)','JPMC-WL Order Book (Internal) Volume ($B)')
    AND (OpStats.product_dwkey IN('RT','HWL') AND OpStats.source_name<>'STP')
  GROUP BY DTA.trading_code, OpStats.product_dwkey;
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm making this too simple, but at a glance it looks to me like there is a field in the first Select that is not part of the group by? ", RegSplits.Volume RegSplitsVol"

Comment: @DavidW thanks - I didn't even see that because I was thinking of it as a `SUM` aggregate, since it is in the subquery!

Comment: Glad to help. Looks like I shoulda just posted that as the answer, but someone else did :) LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Not group by expression" error is very easy to check.
Just compare SELECT expressions with GROUP BY expressions:

```
 SELECT DTA.trading_code Account, 
       OpStats.product_dwkey Platform, 
       SUM(OpStats.risk_amount_adj)/1000000 OpStatsVol, 
       RegSplits.Volume RegSplitsVol
FROM ......
......
GROUP BY DTA.trading_code, 
        OpStats.product_dwkey;
```

There are two elements in SELECT that are not in GROUP BY:

1. `SUM(OpStats.risk_amount_adj)/1000000 OpStatsVol`
2. `RegSplits.Volume RegSplitsVol`

The number 1 is OK - it's an aggregate function, it cannot be in GROUP BY.
**The number 2 caused this error** - it's not an aggregate function, and it is not listed in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: thanks - I didn't even see that because I was thinking of it as a `SUM` aggregate, since it is in the subquery!